# Sending a variable attribute every Ember Data request

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have various Ember models which all need to send the same attribute to the server to identify which information they should modify, I know I could add a non-serialised attribute to each model and set it each time, but that seems messy.

The attribute is on the `Application` controller, and I want it to be sent whenever I save/get/update/etc a model.

Any ideas on how I might do it?

Comment: Try patching `buildURL` in the adapter.

Comment: I need to access the controller though, I can send just a static, non-changing number or string, but this attribute is changeable by the user.